# X by Y matrix in RDBMS

Tags: rdbms

How do I represent an X by Y matrix in a table in an RDBMS? Imagine if I have to exhaustively record all the distances between postal codes in a country, X axis would be "From" and the Y axis would be "To", all intersections where the postal code of From == To will be 0, of course.

Comment: You've just described it: `(from,to,distance)`

Answer (score 1):

A table with postal codes (if you need to store any extra information, for example the city) and a table with 3 columns:

```
postal code 1 id | postal code 2 id | distance between them
```